# how to skip comment lines to read from text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a input.txt file which is having below format.

```
 //schedulers,scott,schedule
 developers,obu,develop
 //testers,welcome, test
```

My requirement is to read the line which is not starts with symbol // using batch script.Here there is only one line which is not starts with symbol // . After reading that line need to tokenize with symbol , and set each token to a var.

I tried this batch script which is not working.

```
 for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (input.txt) do call :process %%i %%j %%k 

 :process
 set var1=%1
 set var2=%2
 set var3=%3
```

will any one help on this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%i in ('findstr /v /c:"//" .\InputFiles\input.txt') do call :Start %%i %%j %%k

:Start 
set firsr=%1
set second=%2
set third=%3
```

Then these values can be used any where in the script.

Answer (score 0):

See the EOF option (goes with token) you can only use single backslash.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 EOF=\" %%i in (input.txt) do call :process %%i %%j %%k
```

Else

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%i in ('findstr /v /c:"\\" input.txt') do call :process %%i %%j %%k
```

Comment: here i need to get the line which is NOT starts with //  .From this example txt file it is in second line. It may be in any line.

Comment: Chang the backslashes to forwardslashes. It hides lines that match. Typing `findstr /?` would have told you that.

Comment: its working... thanks a lot for your precious time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f  "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('findstr  /V "\/\/" "input.txt"') do (call:process %%a %%b %%c) 
exit/b

:process
set "$var1=%1"
set "$var2=%2"
set "$var3=%3"

echo Var1 [%$var1%]
echo Var2 [%$var2%]
echo Var3 [%$var3%]
```

Comment: This works in an awkward way SachaDee as only `%%a` is populated.  You meant to use `delims=,` I assume.